# Flask - how to get id of post after clicking on title

Tags: python, flask

I create a simply website about books. I display the title and description in books.html

```
<div id="book-container">
<p><h2>{{ b.title }}</h2></p>
<div><p>{{ b.description }}</p></div>
<br>
</div>
```

and my route file

```
@app.route('/show_books', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def show_books():
    books = Book.query.all()
    return render_template('books.html', title='Home', books=books)
```

I have problem, because I want to display more information about book after clicking on title. What is the best way to do it? Thanks for help!

Comment: Use `onclick` method in javascript

Comment: OK, I use onclick method in project, but how to get id of clicked title and display all information?

Comment: Just pass the book as an object to your template and use Jinja to display the information you neeed. Basically the same way you already did.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I find other solution but it doesnt work well:

book.html:

```
<div id="book-container">
<a href="{{ url_for('detail_book', title=b.title) }}">{{ b.title }}</a>
<div><p>{{ b.description }}</p></div>
<br> 
</div>
```

routes.py:

```
@app.route('/detail_book/<title>')
def detail_book(title):
    book = Book.query.filter_by(title=title).first_or_404()
    return render_template('detail_book.html', book=book)
```

detail_book.html:

```
DETAILS
<div id="book-container">
    {{ b.id }}
    <h2>{{ b.title }}</h2>
    <div><p>{{ b.description }}</p></div>
    <br>
</div>
```

After clicking on title my url looks like:
    http://localhost:5000/detail_book/Painted%20Man

And in consol: jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'b' is undefined

And I really have no idea how to solve this problem

Comment: You should have enclosed it in a for-loop, something like
 {%for b in books%} <a href="{{ url_for('detail_book', title=b.title) }}">{{ b.title }}</a>
<div><p>{{ b.description }}</p></div>
<br> {%endfor%}

Answer (score 0):

You can use `this` to access the title you click. And `this.id` will give you the id of this element:

```
<div id="book-container">
    <a href=""><h2 id="{{ b.title}}" class="titles">{{ b.title }}</h2></a>
    <div><p>{{ b.description }}</p></div>
    <br>
</div>

<script type=text/javascript>
    $(function(){
        $('.titles').bind('click', function(){
            alert(this.id);
        });
    });
</script>
```

By clicking on the title, you will see a modal indicating the id of the current element (in this case the id will be the title of the book).

The idea here is to add the class `.titles` **to all the titles** that will appear on your page and recover, with `this.id`, the **id** of the element you click. Then you can make an Ajax request to find the additional information corresponding to the specific element on which you clicked.

Comment: Unfortunately, after clicking on title the site is only refreshing

Comment: did you import the jquery library? did you add to your html page the javascript code that I provide in my answer? can you edit your code to show what exactly you have tested?

Comment: So my books.html looks like above: I just copied and pasted code you wrote. And to base.html i add: <script type=text/javascript src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/jquery-3.3.1.min') }}"></script>

Answer (score 0):

It looks like detail_book has a variable book not b.

In your render template you use the variable book.

Below is what the html should look like.

```
DETAILS
<div id="book-container">
    {{ book.id }}
    <h2>{{ book.title }}</h2>
    <div><p>{{ book.description }}</p></div>
    <br>
</div>
```